# CR2032 batteries with Arduino

Tags: arduino, batteries, gps

I'm working on logging GPS values(from u-blox Neo 6m GPS module) to an SD card using an Arduino Pro Mini.

The code I'm working with works without any flaw when we connect the Arduino to the laptop with a USB cable
(power source is from the USB port.)

Once I run my program, all the GPS coordinates along with other data gets saved on the SD card.

As soon as Ichange my power to two CR2032 batteries in series and supply the voltage to the pro mini, data comes for about ten seconds and then the led (pin13) starts blinking super fast (I'm not coding anything to pin13 other than the sck from sd card module for spi communication.)

Then it occured to me that maybe two batteries will not be sufficient, so I used three CR2032 batteries in series and then checked the setup. Now everything works perfectly for about a minute and then snap the led (pin13) starts blinking and ruins the program.

If the led blinks fast, no data gets saved on the SD card.

I'm not sure as to how to solve the problem. Maybe the current is the issue here, but I can't use any other batteries other than CR2032.

Can anyone help me out?

code ive used

````
#include <TinyGPS++.h> // Include the TinyGPS++ library
TinyGPSPlus tinyGPS; // Create a TinyGPSPlus object
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#define GPS_BAUD 9600 // GPS module baud rate. GP3906 defaults to 9600.
#include <Wire.h>
// If you're using an Arduino Uno, RedBoard, or any board that uses the
// 0/1 UART for programming/Serial monitor-ing, use SoftwareSerial:
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define ARDUINO_GPS_RX 2 // GPS TX, Arduino RX pin
#define ARDUINO_GPS_TX 3 // GPS RX, Arduino TX pin
SoftwareSerial ssGPS(ARDUINO_GPS_TX, ARDUINO_GPS_RX); // Create a SoftwareSerial
 #define SDFILE_PIN_CS 10

// Set gpsPort to either ssGPS if using SoftwareSerial or Serial1 if using an
// Arduino with a dedicated hardware serial port
#define gpsPort ssGPS  // Alternatively, use Serial1 on the Leonardo
 File sdFile;
// Define the serial monitor port. On the Uno, and Leonardo this is 'Serial'
//  on other boards this may be 'SerialUSB'
#define SerialMonitor sdFile


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  gpsPort.begin(GPS_BAUD);
  
  pinMode(SDFILE_PIN_CS, OUTPUT);
  
if (!SD.begin()) {
      Serial.println(F("Card failed, or not present"));
      while(1);
      }
      Serial.println(F("card initialized."));
}

void loop()
{ 
  sdFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (sdFile) {
  // print position, altitude, speed, time/date, and satellites:
  printGPSInfo();

  // "Smart delay" looks for GPS data while the Arduino's not doing anything else
  smartDelay(1000); 
  sdFile.close();
      // Uncomment to print to the serial port
      //Serial.println("ENTER SENSOR DATA HERE");
      } 
      else {
      // if the file didn't open, print an error
      Serial.println(F("error opening file."));
      }
}

void printGPSInfo()
{
  // Print latitude, longitude, altitude in feet, course, speed, date, time,
  // and the number of visible satellites.
  printDate();
  SerialMonitor.print("\t");
  printTime();
  SerialMonitor.print("\t");
  SerialMonitor.print(tinyGPS.altitude.meters());
  SerialMonitor.print("\t");
  SerialMonitor.print(tinyGPS.speed.mps());
  SerialMonitor.print("\t");
  SerialMonitor.print(tinyGPS.satellites.value());
  SerialMonitor.print("\t");
  SerialMonitor.print(tinyGPS.location.lat(), 6);
  SerialMonitor.print("\t");
  SerialMonitor.println(tinyGPS.location.lng(), 6);
  
  }

// This custom version of delay() ensures that the tinyGPS object
// is being "fed". From the TinyGPS++ examples.
static void smartDelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do
  {
    // If data has come in from the GPS module
    while (gpsPort.available())
      tinyGPS.encode(gpsPort.read()); // Send it to the encode function
    // tinyGPS.encode(char) continues to "load" the tinGPS object with new
    // data coming in from the GPS module. As full NMEA strings begin to come in
    // the tinyGPS library will be able to start parsing them for pertinent info
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}

// printDate() formats the date into dd/mm/yy.
void printDate()
{
  SerialMonitor.print(tinyGPS.date.day());
  SerialMonitor.print("/");
  SerialMonitor.print(tinyGPS.date.month());
  SerialMonitor.print("/");
  SerialMonitor.print(tinyGPS.date.year());
}

// printTime() formats the time into "hh:mm:ss", and prints leading 0's
// where they're called for.
void printTime()
{
  SerialMonitor.print(tinyGPS.time.hour());
  SerialMonitor.print(":");
  if (tinyGPS.time.minute() < 10) SerialMonitor.print('0');
  SerialMonitor.print(tinyGPS.time.minute());
  SerialMonitor.print(":");
  if (tinyGPS.time.second() < 10) SerialMonitor.print('0');
  SerialMonitor.print(tinyGPS.time.second());
}
```
````

Comment: I can't use any other batteries other than CR2032." Whoever imposed this requirement has set you up for failure.

Comment: Assuming you really mean an Arduino Pro Mini (not the Uno you also mention) you should be able to get a longer run time out of it.  You'll have to get really into the power saving modes of the Arduino and the GPS receiver, though.  Post your code.

Comment: Look at the current requirements of your specific Arduino. Look at the max current that a CR2032 can deliver. Quite likely you have a null set and you got lucky that you didn't cook the batteries

Comment: Also, look at the [Indicative power requirements](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/NEO-6_DataSheet_%28GPS.G6-HW-09005%29.pdf) for the GPS unit and compare that to what a [CR2032](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2032.pdf) cell can supply. It does not look good.

Comment: Putting batteries in *series* will not increase the current capacity, but rather the voltage which can end up damaging things. Did you mean *parallel*?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I actually did hook them up in series. Even though 5v is enough for the setup, i just wanted to make sure of it. But the interesting thing is when i connected two cr2032 batteries in series to make a total of 6v, the module did not work for even a minute. only after i changed it to 9v did it atleast work for 1 min.

Comment: @JRE yea sorry i meant the pro mini and i've uploaded the code too. Please check

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen they'd probably ultimately need both.  In stock form the Arduino's voltage regulator has fairly high dropout so they'd need at least two cells in series.  Then the voltage is likely to sag a lot when subject to an excessive load.   Really the battery design is completely unsuitable, but if it were going to be even attempted they should switch the system to a lower voltage, eliminate the regulator or at least chose a better one or switcher, replace the SD card with an EEPROM or SPI flash of known power draw...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue requires a change of the project requirements.  This is an organizational or business issue, not a technical one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes even i thought we needed both and connected 2 pairs of batteries in series in parallel (6v output but twice the current) but still i end up having the same problem. Is there any other solution other than changing the sd card module?
I have a feeling that the uart connection between the ublox and pro mini might be causing the problem. Because i already tried logging basic data from i2c connection to sd card using battery and it worked(pressure sensor). Only when i use this gps module so i get this problem

Comment: 6 volts is insufficient input for a 5v Arduino.   As previously mentioned you could consider a lower voltage Arduino, but really a serial parallel array of coin cells is silly and this project is destined to fail.  You need to get the requirements changed.  And you need to change the chosen components as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with CR2032 in one of my very first projects! CR2032 simply can't supply enough current, its voltage falls into unusable as soon as you pull anything significant to power the MCU (I had STM32 blue pill and it pulled single CR2032 nominal 3.2V almost immediately down to borderline 2.65V with full fresh CR2032).

The sulution for me was to replace it with a tiny 250mah li-io, it's only slightly greater than CR2032 and certainly comparable to two CR2032 in size while being rechargeable and giving the required power without a problem. But yeah, voltage levels are different, you know it.

Requirements are requirements of course, but you can't fly if you wave oars, it's an impossible task for CR2032 (we're talking about practical realistic stuff and not 25 batteries in parallel), as many around here pointed out. You just have to prove this point and srsly go for a tiny 150mah - 300mah (which is totally comparable to CR2032 btw). Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

A CR2032 battery, or many in series, could perhaps power up the Arduino.

Saving data to the SD card can take bursts of current up to 300 mA depending on the SD card make/model/speedgrade.

One CR2032 battery manufacturer says the maximum current drawn from battery is 10mA, so it might be possible to parallel up to 30 batteries to make it work, if that is the requirement.

So in short, there is no practical way do it with CR2032 batteries.